# Google Nexus 7 4.3 unknown in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

i have Google Nexus 7 Version 4.3 i had installed the driver but when i attempt to send the project from Eclipse its appear offline and unknown , I've googled it and installed last drivers but still same problem

this is screen shoot of Eclipse

[image]

please guys any advice ?

Comment: When i face this issue, my first attempt is to kill the current server and restart new one. adb kill-server and adb start-server is command.

Comment: still getting same problem !

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quote old now, but I stumbled across it while trying to solve the same error on my S3 after updating it to 4.3. I enabled USB debugging, but when I plugged into Eclipse, the device shows as Offline. When I ran

```
adb devices
```

it actually reported that my device was unauthorised. Turns out that you have to authorise the computer to use USB debugging with android 4.3. So I disabled usb debugging, unplugged the USB cable from the phone, re-enabled debugging then replugged the USB, and sure enough a message popped up asking for authorisation.

All works fine now. Hope this helps someone.